# Why doesn't this perl code notice new files added to directory during execution?

Tags: perl

I need to write a Perl program where I have a bunch of files which are written to local disk. I have to monitor them, and after any file is no longer increasing in size, use SFTP to transfer it to another location.

So something like this:

1. Check all the files one by one that are coming to drop folder
2. If file is still growing, then move to next file
3. If file is not growing anymore, then use SFTP to move it another location
4. Loop back to number 1.

---

This is what I try to get work in Win first before moving it to Linux. Problem is, that this runs only one time good, not looping --> if new files are added  during run time, those files are untouchables ...

`

```
 while (1) {

  while (my $filename = readdir(DIR) ) {
   print $filename , "\n";
   my $size1 = -s $filename;
   print "$size1\n";
   sleep 2;
   my $size2 = -s $filename;
   print "$size2\n";

      if ($size1 == $size2) {
      move($filename,"c:/temp/perl/out");
 }

}
```

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me" plattform

Comment: Start by showing us the code you've written for this so far

Comment: What is writing these files?

Comment: Another system is writing big audio and video files on-the-fly to the folder and these need move another place as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readdir() only iterates through the files which were present when the directory was opened with the opendir() call. You need to call opendir() within the outer while loop. A code example from [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1113829):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (opendir my $dirh, "/somewhere/else")
{
    while (my $file = readdir $dirh)
    {
        print "$file\n";
    }
    sleep 1;
}
```